# 'Range' Input type doesn't slide on React.js document, but works on codepen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  trying to implement a range slider into my React app but when I type in the code, the slider does not work at all?

It doesn't drag side to side. Clicking on it also does not move it. Although, if I use the exact same code on codepen, the slider works completely fine.

I have tried researching this but I cannot find a clear answer. Anybody have any idea what can be wrong?

The code in question:

```
<input
            type="range"
            min="1"
            max="100"
            value="50"
            class="slider"
            id="myRange"
          />
```

Here is my app in its entirety.

```
import "./App.scss"
import React, { useState } from "react"

function App() {
  const [firstColorInput, setFirstColorInput] = useState("")
  const [secondColorInput, setSecondColorInput] = useState("")

  const [mode, setMode] = useState("single")

  const handlefirstColorChange = (e) => {
    setFirstColorInput(e.target.value)
    console.log(firstColorInput)
  }

  const handlesecondColorChange = (e) => {
    setSecondColorInput(e.target.value)
    console.log(secondColorInput)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        background:
          mode === "single"
            ? firstColorInput
            : `linear-gradient(${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput})`,
      }}
    >
      <div class="container">
        <div id="colour_picker">
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handlefirstColorChange}
            value={firstColorInput}
            id="input_first"
            placeholder={
              mode === "single"
                ? "Enter color name or code"
                : "Enter First Colour"
            }
            class="inputs"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handlesecondColorChange}
            value={secondColorInput}
            style={{ display: mode === "single" ? "none" : "block" }}
            id="input_second"
            placeholder={mode === "single" ? "" : "Enter Second Colour"}
            class="inputs"
          />

          <button
            onClick={() => setMode(mode === "single" ? "gradient" : "single")}
          >
            {mode === "single" ? "Single Colour" : "Gradient"}
          </button>

          <input
            type="range"
            min="1"
            max="100"
            value="50"
            class="slider"
            id="myRange"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Show us your `App.scss`

Comment: I deleted it all just to rule it out, I have tried it purely without ANY SCSS or normal CSS. Still the same result, so that is ruled out

Answer (score 3):

```
value="50"
```

In react, this tells it to set the value to 50, and never change it.

You have two options: you can either run the input as an uncontrolled component, by giving it a default value:

```
defaultValue="50"
```

Or you can do it as a controlled component by having a state variable:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("50");

//...
<input
  type="range"
  min="1"
  max="100"
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
  class="slider"
  id="myRange"
/>
```

If you're not sure which one you need, do the controlled version. For more information on the difference between controlled and uncontrolled components, see [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: Perfect. Works like a dream! I learn something new about react every day :)